# How to make a rule when a date is higher than a specific date in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I'm searching for a formula to have a value of a variable `xxxxx` only when the date is higher than '2020-07-17'.

I have tried many options, but none work so far.

```
case when Date>20200717 then xxxxx
end

case when Date>'2020-07-17' then xxxxx
end
```

I also tried formulas with REGEXP_MATCH

```
case when REGEXP_MATCH(Date, '2017-07-1[0-9]') then xxxxx
end
```

My Date is a "Date (YYYYMMDD)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 0) Summary

- Use **EITHER** #1: New Recommended approach as per the [17 Sep 2020 Date and Time Update](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6311467#sep-17-2020);
- **OR** #2: The original suggestion, prior to the [17 Sep 2020 Date and Time Update](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6311467#sep-17-2020).

## 1) Recommended Suggestion (Using the [17 Sep 2020 Date and Time Update](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6311467#sep-17-2020) fields)

The single [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below creates a Text Date field using [`FORMAT_DATETIME`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9730334) function, then the [`CAST`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7280720) function to ensure that the Type is set to Number, after which values matching `20200717` (17 Jul 2020) display values of the `ifr_ds_PV` field while other values (not matching `20200717`) are treated as `NULL`:

```
CASE
  WHEN CAST(FORMAT_DATETIME("%Y%m%d", Date) AS NUMBER ) > 20200717 THEN ifr_ds_PV
  ELSE NULL
END
```

Added a [New Page](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/feacad20-cc9e-4034-be5e-8f50cc6e5fec/page/WVlDC) to the Editable Google Data Studio Report and a GIF to demonstrate:

[image]

## 2) Original Suggestion (Using the pre [17 Sep 2020 Date and Time Update](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6311467#sep-17-2020) fields)

### 2.1) dateNumber

It can be achieved by first creating a **Date Number** field at the Data Source; create the [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below and ensure that the Type is set to Numeric > Number:

```
CAST(Date AS NUMBER)
```

GIF to visualise the process:

[image]

### 2.2) Calculated Field(s)

The Calculated Fields can then be adapted by using the newly created `Date#` field (which follows the **YYYYMMDD** format), for example:

```
CASE
  WHEN dateNumber > 20200717 THEN ifr_ds_PV
  ELSE NULL
END
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/feacad20-cc9e-4034-be5e-8f50cc6e5fec) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a calculated field `_Date` as:

> CAST(FORMAT_DATETIME("%Y%m%d", Date) AS NUMBER )

and make sure it can be used as a metric.

Then use that to build the CASE statement, lie this:

```
CASE
  WHEN LAST(_Date) > 20200717 THEN xxx
  ELSE yyyy
END
```