# Vertical reference line in Google Data Studio line chart

Tags: looker-studio

I'd like to add a vertical reference line in a line chart at the position of the current month. Any way to do this?

Current chart:
[image: Chart without vertical reference line]

Desired chart:
[image: Chart with vertical reference line]

Answer (score 10):

The [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below (where `Date` represents the name of the Date field, and `Metric`, the name of the current metric) adds a Bar on the current month:

### 1) Data Tab

- ***Chart***: [Time Series](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7059697)
- ***Dimension***: `Date`; ***Type***: `Year Month`
- ***Metric #1***: `Metric`
- ***Metric #2***: `Today`

```
IF(DATETIME_TRUNC(Date, MONTH) = DATETIME_TRUNC(TODAY(), MONTH), 1, NULL)
```

### 2) Style Tab

- ***Metric #1***: Line; ***Axis***: Left
- ***Metric #2***: Bar; ***Axis***: Right

### 3) Remove Right Y-Axis

- ***Right Y-Axis (Custom Tick Interval)***: 1
- ***Shape***: Add a shape over the 0 to hide the last visible value of the Right Y-Axis

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/b96e98ea-e14b-4504-9389-e883076d6845) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bxqzinoo39dG4z8DV3TZHr2glJpDB9MVj_9qK-jlofQ/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this example below (borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63114661/how-to-make-a-rule-when-a-date-is-higher-than-a-specific-date-in-google-data-stu)).  After you change the date to a number, you can put this new value on the right axis and make it a bar.

```
CASE
  WHEN CAST(FORMAT_DATETIME("%Y%m%d", Date) AS NUMBER ) = [YOUR DESIRED DATE] THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END
```